# Finding the inverse of $2+\sqrt{5}+2\sqrt{7}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Finding the inverse of $2+\sqrt{5}+2\sqrt{7}$ in the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7})$.

I know that all the elements of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7})$ are of the form:

$a+b\sqrt{5}+c\sqrt{7}+d\sqrt{35}$, where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Q} $

So I could simply solve: $(2+\sqrt{5}+2\sqrt{7})(a+b\sqrt{5}+c\sqrt{7}+d\sqrt{35})=1$

Which I believe works. Is there a better way of solving this problem?

Comment: This will work - you end up solving four equations in four unknowns. This view of the problem actually leads to the view of $2+\sqrt{5}+2\sqrt{7}$ as a $4\times 4$ matrix. But, as others have pointed out, there is a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Consider the product $(2+\sqrt{5}+2\sqrt{7})(2-\sqrt{5}+2\sqrt{7})(2+\sqrt{5}-2\sqrt{7})(2-\sqrt{5}-2\sqrt{7})$.

Comment: I think I see your idea, that's like a  "conjugate" right?

Comment: Yes, it is essentially "all the conjugates." @KingGhidorah

Comment: Yes, the product I mentioned will be rational, indeed an integer, and now we have an expression for the reciprocal. This is not the most efficient way of computing the reciprocal, but it has the advantage that it is readily extended.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{5}+2\sqrt{7}}
&=\frac{2+\sqrt{5}-2\sqrt{7}}{(2+\sqrt{5})^2-28}\\
&=\frac{2+\sqrt{5}-2\sqrt{7}}{-19+4\sqrt{5}}\\
&=\frac{(2+\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{7})(-19-4\sqrt{5})}{361-80}\\
&=\dots
\end{align}